# Blowups of log del Pezzo surfaces at smooth points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

It follows from [a result of Küchle](https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9410011.pdf) that the blowup of a smooth del Pezzo surface will again be del Pezzo, provided that the inequality $-K^2>0$ remains true after blowing-up.

Let's say a surface is log del Pezzo if it has at worst log terminal singularities and some multiple of the anticanonical divisor is ample Cartier. My question is if the same holds for blowups of log del Pezzo surfaces at smooth points. This is, does $-K^2>0$ still guarantee ampleness of the anticanonical in this case?

I haven't been able to locate a source stating this or explicitly providing a counterexample. It's also not clear to me how one would use Küchle's result. Either of these would also be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** [Remark 2.9 in this paper by Cavey and Prince](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.09213.pdf) seems to indicate that this is true for blowups of $\mathbb{P}(1,1,k)$. But it could be something particular to these surfaces.

Comment: Do you mean the blowup in a general point (as seems to be the case in the linked paper)?

Comment: @WillSawin yes, even assuming some sort of very general position would be OK.